# Spatialite function to generate a blob from a geometry

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, spatialite, pyqt

Using QGIS Python API, I want to avoid updating geometry with an UPDATE sql command.

Why? I'm using a `QSqlRelationalTableModel` (see [model-view programming](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/model-view-programming.html) if curious) and there are built-in [editing strategy](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qsqltablemodel.html#setEditStrategy) I want to benefit.

My issue is that for geometry, I should update the model content with a Spatialite geometry blob ([specs](http://www.gaia-gis.it/gaia-sins/BLOB-Geometry.html)).

I didn't found any blob functions in Spatialite for geometry, so I could do `function_transform_geometry_to_spatialite_blob(MakePoint(0, 0, 4326))` and it returns a blob with geometry embedded as a text I can use to update my Geometry field within the model.
Are there any I missed?

Maybe, it's not the right approach. You may have another suggestions/opinions.

PS: I know about http://blog.vitu.ch/10112013-1201/qgis-relations and I've seen [this discussion](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/91647/qgis-relations-widget-in-custom-form) but it does not seem as flexible as `QSqlRelationalTableModel` combined with [`QDataWidgetMapper`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qdatawidgetmapper.html) (but I could be wrong)

Comment: You could make calls to the underlying spatialite functions (in C++, rather than SQL). I'd caution that if you do that, you are working around QGIS which may cause other issues later. Perhaps making this less abstract would help - show a small, executable example and say what you want to do instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was obvious and I didn't read well the RTFM. See [this discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/spatialite-users/tsz7QViAKyk) on the Spatialite mailing list.

The answer is:

```
SELECT ST_GeomFromText('POINT(1 2)', 4326);
```

or

```
SELECT MakePoint(1, 2, 4326);
```

To make result as a text, do:

```
SELECT hex(MakePoint(1, 2, 4326));
```